# How to Setup my ssh keys on my BigBlueButton server?

Tags: git, github, ssh, bigbluebutton

I'm trying to setup a development environment for BigBlueButton: https://code.google.com/p/bigbluebutton/wiki/Developing#Setup_a_Development_Environment

One of the steps is:

> Next, using your GitHub account, do the following
>
> 1. Setup your ssh keys on your BigBlueButton server
> 2. Fork the BigBlueButton repository into your GitHub account
> 3. Clone your repository into your `~/dev` folder"

I'm having trouble with - "1. Setup your ssh keys on your BigBlueButton server"

I've created an ssh key on my GitHub account but I don't understand how to setup it with my server.

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you did already setup ssh keys for GitHub, you should have on your BigBlueButton server (in your `~/.ssh`) a private and a public key (as explained in "[Generating SSH keys](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/)").

Then you can fork the [`bigbluebutton/bigbluebutton`](https://github.com/bigbluebutton/bigbluebutton) repo (an operation which involves only GitHub), before cloning it on your server in order to develop.

Your server will then be used both for BigBlueButton server and for development, since the documentation does mention:

> Before you can start developing on BigBlueButton, you need a working BigBlueButton 0.81 server.
>
> **We emphasize that your BigBlueButton server must be working before you start setting up the development environment**.
>   Be sure that you can login, start sessions, join the audio bridge, share your webcam, and record and playback sessions -- all using the built-in API demos.
>
> By starting with a working BigBlueButton server, you have the ability to switch back-and-forth between the default packaged components and your modified equivalents.